# setxkbmap setting lost when I switch keyboard layout in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, ubuntu-16.04, ctrl, capslock

I set my Caps Lock to be a Ctrl in Ubuntu 16.04 using:

`setxkbmap -option 'caps:ctrl_modifier'`

But when I change my keyboard from En to Cs, the Caps Lock becomes a Caps Lock again, not a Ctrl.

To fix it, I have to execute the above `setxkbmap` command again from a terminal.

How can I make the setting permanent, even if I switch keyboard layouts?

Comment: I guess all you need is to add `us,cs` at the end of your `setxkbmap` command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to make the options set by setxkbmap permanent, add them to `/etc/default/keyboard` as follows:

```
--- a/etc/default/keyboard
+++ b/etc/default/keyboard
@@ -5,6 +5,6 @@
 XKBMODEL="pc105"
 XKBLAYOUT="us"
 XKBVARIANT=""
-XKBOPTIONS=""
+XKBOPTIONS="caps:ctrl_modifier"

 BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Then the option `caps:ctrl_modifier` will be set even when the keyboard layout is switched from En to any other language.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any clue why the `setxkbmap` settings are constantly overridden when added to `.bashrc`? I don't have this problem with any other program, just `setxkbmap` misbehaves randomly.

Comment: @timgeb, unfortunately I have no idea. I am glad I at least figured out a solution that works, but why it works, that I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try setting this in the Xorg config as well. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg#Using_X_configuration_files for the proper syntax and where to define the options. This also has other good information around using setxkbmap and it's options.

Answer (score -2):

I just solved this. After trying a bunch of different things, in Ubuntu 16.04:
- Go to /.bashrc (you can open up the terminal and type vim .bashrc (or use your favorite editor).
- Add the command at the end! in my case I did: setxkbmap -option ctrl:swapcaps

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve it. Your approach is equivalent to what I do (I actually have the `setxkbmap -option 'caps:ctrl_modifier'` in my `~/.bashrc`). So try your approach, and then change the keyboard layout from `En` to any other language by first adding it in System Settings -> Text Entry, and then changing it in the keyboard layout icon in your tray. When you do that, the `setxkbmap` setting is lost.